# Operating on a subset of a DF: impact of different syntax

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I want to operate on a subset of data in a df using python and pandas. I'm using apply to do the work. Here is the data held in df0:

```
date         A         B        FX
1/1/2019   1.7379    1.7379   1.337562
2/1/2019   1.6604    1.7379   1.336279
```

I'm changing units in the data in column A using column FX, and leaving column B as is.  The first code I use is:

```
df0.loc[:,'A']=df0.loc[:,'A'].apply(lambda x: x / df0['FX'] * 1.055056)
```

This works fine, producing the data I'm looking for:

```
date         A         B        FX
1/1/2019   1.3708    1.7379   1.337562
2/1/2019   1.3109    1.7379   1.336279
```

The second code piece of code provides the same answers.

```
df1.loc[:,'A']=df1.apply(lambda x: x / df1['FX'] * 1.055056)
```

Obviously I'm fairly new at this - can someone explain to me in plain english the difference in my two lines of code and why they produce the results they do?

Secondly, if there is a more effective way to operate on a subset of a DF, I would love to hear about that.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comments below. For more color, there is actually hundreds of rows and columns in the dataset, and I choose a subset via a list. The actual code would look more like (based on comments below - thanks all):

```
df0[list]=df0[list].apply(lambda x: x / df0['FX'] * 1.055056)
```

Or perhaps it is better to avoid lamba and use (I believe this would be correct):

```
df0[list]=df0[list] / df0['FX'] * 1.055056
```

Comment: What is happening  the second df1 case is that you are performing that lambda function on all columns of the dataframe, but you are assign only the 'A' column base on the .loc[:'A'] infront of the equals sign.  It first case, you are slicing the 'A' column and only performing the lambda function on one column and then reassigning the results back to 'A'.  I suspect that the first statement is much more efficient than the second.

Comment: If you are operating on a whole column, rather than using `df.loc[:,'A']`, you can simplify with `df['A']`

Comment: And then your formula is much simpler without lambda: `df0['A'] / df0['FX'] * 1.055056`. Unless I am reading wrong, there is no subsets here but operations on Series (i.e., columns of DataFrame).

Comment: @Parfait perhaps my use of "subset" was not correct. In this case I am working on a time series - the actual data is hundreds of columns, and I want to do this operation on a list of them.  In each case though, I guess because the index (date) is in order, i am operating on the whole column in the "right order"